# Escape an asterisk in DOS

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

I would like to rename a file in DOS. As a result, a dot and an asterisk should be appended to the file name. For example:

```
rename text.log text.log.*
```

However this returns:

```
text.log..
```

I have also tried to escape the * as follows:

```
rename text.log text.log.\*
```

But no way! Do you guys know how I can rename this file appending an .* to the string text.log by using a cmd shell?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you still working in **MS-DOS**??

Comment: Try renaming the file from Windows Explorer.  If you use an illegal character it will give you a little popup showing you a list of characters you cannot use when naming a file.

Answer (score 4):

You can't - `*` is a reserved character and so cannot be used in a filename.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words